# I am getting errors when trying to run flutter app. The parameter can't have a value of 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the errors that I get please tell me what to do?

lib/models.dart:21:21: Error: The parameter 'description' can't have a value of 'null' because
of its type
'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
WeatherInfo({this.description, this.icon});

lib/models.dart:21:39: Error: The parameter 'icon' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String',
but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
WeatherInfo({this.description, this.icon});

lib/models.dart:33:25: Error: The parameter 'temperature' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type
'double', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
TemperatureInfo({this.temperature});

lib/models.dart:50:25: Error: The parameter 'cityName' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type
'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier. WeatherResponse({this.cityName, this.tempInfo, this.weatherInfo});

lib/models.dart:50:40: Error: The parameter 'tempInfo' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type
'TemperatureInfo', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
'TemperatureInfo' is from 'package:flutterapp/models.dart' ('lib/models.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
WeatherResponse({this.cityName, this.tempInfo, this.weatherInfo});

lib/models.dart:50:55: Error: The parameter 'weatherInfo' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type
'WeatherInfo', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
'WeatherInfo' is from 'package:flutterapp/models.dart' ('lib/models.dart').
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
WeatherResponse({this.cityName, this.tempInfo, this.weatherInfo});

lib/main.dart:19:19: Error: Field '_response' should be initialized because its type 'WeatherResponse' doesn't
allow null.
'WeatherResponse' is from 'package:flutterapp/models.dart' ('lib/models.dart').
WeatherResponse _response;

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not the correct way to ask questions, I'd suggest you to: 1. Give more info and concise context, 2. Possibly attach some code and 3. to format your question with the backticks before and after your code `just like this`

Answer (score 0):

`This is the line with error.`

```
  WeatherResponse _response;
```

Non-nullable instance field '_response' must be initialized.